# how to use trained model to test new sentence in python (sklearn)

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp, data-science, classification

I have code to training the model for `multi class text classification` and it's work but I can't use that model. this is my code for training

```
def training(df):
X = df.Text
y = df.Tags
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.3, random_state=42)
lr = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer()),
               ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
               ('clf', LogisticRegression()),
               ])

lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred1 = lr.predict(X_test)
print(f"Accuracy is : {accuracy_score(y_pred1, y_test)}")
print(lr.predict('ماست کم چرب 900 گرمی رامک'))
```

when I run the code got this this result `Accuracy is : 0.9957983193277311` and this error

- Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\Python\NLP Project\Beta_00\Level0\handleClassification.py", line 100, in 
  training(df)

  File "E:\Python\NLP Project\Beta_00\Level0\handleClassification.py", line 85, in training
  print(lr.predict('ماست کم چرب 900 گرمی رامک'))

  File "E:\Python\NLP Project\Beta_00\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\metaestimators.py"
  line 120, in 
  out = lambda *args, **kwargs: self.fn(obj, *args, **kwargs)

  File "E:\Python\NLP Project\Beta_00\venv\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py", line 418, in
  predict
  Xt = transform.transform(Xt)

  File "E:\Python\NLP Project\Beta_00\venv\lib\site-
  packages\sklearn\feature_extraction\text.py", line 1248, in transform
  raise ValueError(
  ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.

Comment: Accuracy should be `accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred1)`

Comment: @BlackRaven I don't get it! what did you mean?

Comment: @BlackRaven I have problem with `print(lr.predict('ماست کم چرب 900 گرمی رامک'))` this

Comment: `print(f"Accuracy is : {accuracy_score(y_pred1, y_test)}")` should be `(y_test, y_pred1)`

Comment: @BlackRaven Ohhhhhh I see that, but it's not my problem

Comment: How about `lr.predict(['ماست کم چرب 900 گرمی رامک'])` ?

Comment: @BlackRaven yes I got the result but the `ValueError: Iterable over raw text documents expected, string object received.` error still show up

Comment: The input for `lr.predict()` should be an array of string

Comment: @BlackRaven hey man, tnx I fixed it with your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below lines need correction:

```
lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_pred1 = lr.predict(X_test)
print(f"Accuracy is : {accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred1)}")   #<--- here
print(lr.predict(['ماست کم چرب 900 گرمی رامک']))   #<--- here
```

The line `lr.predict(input)` should take in an input of 'array' type.